# C# generating XML documentation

Tags: c#, xml-documentation, docfx

I have created a new C# WinForms project running on .NET Framework 4.7.2 and I would like to create a pdf documentation from XML generated file. I've managed to install VS docfx.console package as described in item 3 [here](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx_getting_started.html). When I build my sollution, it creates `_site` folder with `index.html, toc.html, ImageArt.html, ImageArt.Form1.html`(where `ImageArt` is my projects namespace). But I cant see any of other classes of functions(which I documented using XML comments) in created documentation(not even my Main function). Any idea whats wrong or how can I add my other classes/functions to exported documentation ?

EDIT:
XML file is normally generated under bin/Debug/ folder, and looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<doc>


-<assembly>

<name>ImageArt</name>

</assembly>


-<members>


-<member name="F:ImageArt.Form1.components">

<summary>Required designer variable. </summary>

</member>


-<member name="M:ImageArt.Form1.Dispose(System.Boolean)">

<summary>Clean up any resources being used. </summary>

<param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>

</member>


-<member name="M:ImageArt.Form1.InitializeComponent">

<summary>Required method for Designer support - do not modifythe contents of this method with the code editor. </summary>

</member>


-<member name="M:ImageArt.Program.Main">

<summary>The main entry point for the application. </summary>

</member>


-<member name="T:ImageArt.NewClass">

<summary>Summary for newClass </summary>

</member>


-<member name="T:ImageArt.Properties.Resources">

<summary>A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc. </summary>

</member>


-<member name="P:ImageArt.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager">

<summary>Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class. </summary>

</member>


-<member name="P:ImageArt.Properties.Resources.Culture">

<summary>Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for allresource lookups using this strongly typed resource class. </summary>

</member>

</members>

</doc>
```

As you can see, it contains member item for `Main` method and `NewClass` class, yet they are missing in generated HTML documentation.

Comment: Have you enabled `XML documentation file` under Project Settings --> Build?

Comment: @AlexB. yes I did, my XML file is constructed in bin/debug/ folder